# Javascript / Python Character ASCII Checking

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ascii

I am kind of stuck.  I have Python code that talks to a C++ Wrapper that has a Boost Library that uses String as a parameter.  In my python code I can talk to this wrapper correctly if I use str(x).  The problem is if I use str("£") it returns an escape code.

How can I let this pass into the C++ Method as string if the string itself returns a hex code.

My first idea is to use an encoder and remove the character.  And the second idea is to put on javascript serverside code to stop the user in the first instance entering a non ascii character.

Here is the JS Lint.  http://jsfiddle.net/M5Xqg/  Can someone adjust to why its returning a '£' as a valid ascii character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this '\xc2\xa3' with str("£") because your Python interpreter converts "£" symbol to UTF-8 (it's you default locale I think). If you want to get ASCII string, you should do "£".encode('ascii') but you will get an UnicodeDecodeError exception because it's not an ASCII character, so you need some filtering.

Even if you make check on client-side with JS the request still can be made straight-forward using curl tool or anything similar, so it would be better to have check on client side and filtering on server side.

On server side you can do something like that:

```
>>> s = "ascii text 123 £ 456 go go"
>>> t = filter(lambda x: x.isalnum(), s)
>>> print t
"ascii text 123  456 go go"
```

But this code will filter all non-alphanumeric characters. If you want to allow all printable ASCII chars, try this instead:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
>>> t = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)
>>> print t
'ascii text 123  456 go go'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the library is wrapped in Python code, why not do the check in Python, rather than Javascript? The mistake is one Python wouldn't let you make. In your if statement:

```
(asciiNumber = 20)
```

Should be:

```
(asciiNumber == 20)
```